# section content scaling with background

Tags: css

I am trying to stop my section content from scaling with my section background. the scale of the background is perfect but it seems to make the content scale also, I am using gsap library I have tried creating a container inside the section and give it absolute but nothing I do stops the content inside from scaling

```js
//First the variables our app is going to use need to be declared

 //References to DOM elements
 var $window = $(window);
 var $document = $(document);
 //Only links that starts with #
 var $navButtons = $("nav a").filter("[href^=#]");
 var $navGoPrev = $(".go-prev");
 var $navGoNext = $(".go-next");
 var $sectionsContainer = $(".sections-container");
 var $sections = $(".section");
 var $currentSection = $sections.first();

 //Animating flag - is our app animating
 var isAnimating = false;

 //The height of the window
 var pageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

 //Key codes for up and down arrows on keyboard. We'll be using this to navigate change sections using the keyboard
 var keyCodes = {
  UP  : 38,
  DOWN: 40
 }

 //Going to the first section
 goToSection($currentSection);


 /*
 *   Adding event listeners
 * */

 $window.on("resize", onResize).resize();
 $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", onMouseWheel);
 $document.on("keydown", onKeyDown);
 $navButtons.on("click", onNavButtonClick);
 $navGoPrev.on("click", goToPrevSection);
 $navGoNext.on("click", goToNextSection);

 /*
 *   Internal functions
 * */


 /*
 *   When a button is clicked - first get the button href, and then section to the container, if there's such a container
 * */
 function onNavButtonClick(event)
 {
  //The clicked button
  var $button = $(this);

  //The section the button points to
  var $section = $($button.attr("href"));

  //If the section exists, we go to it
  if($section.length)
  {
   goToSection($section);
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 }

 /*
 *   Getting the pressed key. Only if it's up or down arrow, we go to prev or next section and prevent default behaviour
 *   This way, if there's text input, the user is still able to fill it
 * */
 function onKeyDown(event)
 {

  var PRESSED_KEY = event.keyCode;

  if(PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.UP)
  {
   goToPrevSection();
   event.preventDefault();
  }
  else if(PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.DOWN)
  {
   goToNextSection();
   event.preventDefault();
  }

 }

 /*
 *   When user scrolls with the mouse, we have to change sections
 * */
 function onMouseWheel(event)
 {
  //Normalize event wheel delta
  var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 30 || -event.originalEvent.detail;

  //If the user scrolled up, it goes to previous section, otherwise - to next section
  if(delta < -1)
  {
   goToNextSection();
  }
  else if(delta > 1)
  {
   goToPrevSection();
  }

  event.preventDefault();
 }

 /*
 *   If there's a previous section, section to it
 * */
 function goToPrevSection()
 {
  if($currentSection.prev().length)
  {
   goToSection($currentSection.prev());
  }
 }

 /*
 *   If there's a next section, section to it
 * */
 function goToNextSection()
 {
  if($currentSection.next().length)
  {
   goToSection($currentSection.next());
  }
 }

 /*
 *   Actual transition between sections
 * */
 function goToSection($section)
 {
  //If the sections are not changing and there's such a section
  if(!isAnimating && $section.length)
  {
   //setting animating flag to true
   isAnimating = true;
      
      
      
   

   //Sliding to current section
            TweenLite.set($currentSection, {autoAlpha: 0, display: 'none'});
      
   $currentSection = $section;
      
            TweenLite.set($currentSection, {display: 'block'});
   TweenLite.fromTo($currentSection, 0.6, {scale: 0.9, autoAlpha: 0}, {scale: 1, autoAlpha: 1, ease: Power1.easeOut, onComplete: onSectionChangeEnd, onCompleteScope: this});
      
      
    

   //Animating menu items
   TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter(".active"), 0.5, {className: "-=active"});

   TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter("[href=#" + $currentSection.attr("id") + "]"), 0.5, {className: "+=active"});

  }
 }

 /*
 *   Once the sliding is finished, we need to restore "isAnimating" flag.
 *   You can also do other things in this function, such as changing page title
 * */
 function onSectionChangeEnd()
 {
  isAnimating = false;
 }

 /*
 *   When user resize it's browser we need to know the new height, so we can properly align the current section
 * */
 function onResize(event)
 {

  //This will give us the new height of the window
  var newPageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

  /*
  *   If the new height is different from the old height ( the browser is resized vertically ), the sections are resized
  * */
  if(pageHeight !== newPageHeight)
  {
   pageHeight = newPageHeight;

   //This can be done via CSS only, but fails into some old browsers, so I prefer to set height via JS
   TweenLite.set([$sectionsContainer, $sections], {height: pageHeight + "px"});

   //The current section should be always on the top
   TweenLite.set($sectionsContainer, {scrollTo: {y: pageHeight * $currentSection.index() }});
  }

 }
```

```css
body, div, p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
 background-color: #000;
}


h1{
 color: #fff;
}


.sections-container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 10;
}

.section {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#section-1 {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.section .centered h1 {
 text-align: center;
}
.section .centered p {
 text-align: center;
}
#section-1 {
 background-color: #5A4748;
}
#section-2 {
 background-color: #45959b;
}
#section-3 {
 background-color: #778899;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script> 



<div class="sections-container">
 
 
    <div class="section" id="section-1">
     <div class="centered">
            <h1>1</h1>            
        </div>
    </div>
 
 
    <div class="section" id="section-2">
        <div class="centered">
            <h1>2</h1>            
        </div>
    </div>
 
 
    <div class="section" id="section-3">
        <div class="centered">
            <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
    </div> 
 
</div>
```

Comment: By preventing the content from scaling, do you mean you're trying to limit the size of the section container? If so have you tried setting a max-width/height for it?

Comment: if you look at the full page and you scroll you will see the number inside scales with the section scale @Keno Clayton

Comment: the number represents the content so when it changes when you scroll I want the content to show but only the background image to scale animate @KenoClayton

Comment: You'll want to separate the elements then. Either make the content inside `position:absolute` or wrap the content and the BG in a div and only animate the BG. I'll write a full answer when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be what you're looking for? I basically added a background div

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

```
#background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

which is assigned a background class based on the section which is currently visible.

```
var $background = $("#background");

...

$background.classList = "";

TweenLite.set($background, {
  className: '+=bg-' + ($sections.index($currentSection) + 1)
});

TweenLite.fromTo($background, 0.6, {
  scale: 0.9,
  autoAlpha: 0
}, {
  scale: 1,
  autoAlpha: 1,
  ease: Power1.easeOut,
  onComplete: onSectionChangeEnd,
  onCompleteScope: this
});
```

You can choose to remove the autoAlpha tween on the section numbers if you so prefer.

```js
//First the variables our app is going to use need to be declared

//References to DOM elements
var $window = $(window);
var $document = $(document);
//Only links that starts with #
var $navButtons = $("nav a").filter("[href^=#]");
var $navGoPrev = $(".go-prev");
var $navGoNext = $(".go-next");
var $sectionsContainer = $(".sections-container");
var $sections = $(".section");
var $background = $("#background");
var $currentSection = $sections.first();

//Animating flag - is our app animating
var isAnimating = false;

//The height of the window
var pageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

//Key codes for up and down arrows on keyboard. We'll be using this to navigate change sections using the keyboard
var keyCodes = {
  UP: 38,
  DOWN: 40
}

//Going to the first section
goToSection($currentSection);


/*
 *   Adding event listeners
 * */

$window.on("resize", onResize).resize();
$window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", onMouseWheel);
$document.on("keydown", onKeyDown);
$navButtons.on("click", onNavButtonClick);
$navGoPrev.on("click", goToPrevSection);
$navGoNext.on("click", goToNextSection);

/*
 *   Internal functions
 * */


/*
 *   When a button is clicked - first get the button href, and then section to the container, if there's such a container
 * */
function onNavButtonClick(event) {
  //The clicked button
  var $button = $(this);

  //The section the button points to
  var $section = $($button.attr("href"));

  //If the section exists, we go to it
  if ($section.length) {
    goToSection($section);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

/*
 *   Getting the pressed key. Only if it's up or down arrow, we go to prev or next section and prevent default behaviour
 *   This way, if there's text input, the user is still able to fill it
 * */
function onKeyDown(event) {

  var PRESSED_KEY = event.keyCode;

  if (PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.UP) {
    goToPrevSection();
    event.preventDefault();
  } else if (PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.DOWN) {
    goToNextSection();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}

/*
 *   When user scrolls with the mouse, we have to change sections
 * */
function onMouseWheel(event) {
  //Normalize event wheel delta
  var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 30 || -event.originalEvent.detail;

  //If the user scrolled up, it goes to previous section, otherwise - to next section
  if (delta < -1) {
    goToNextSection();
  } else if (delta > 1) {
    goToPrevSection();
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}

/*
 *   If there's a previous section, section to it
 * */
function goToPrevSection() {
  console.log($currentSection.prev().length > 0);
  if ($currentSection.prev().length) {
    goToSection($currentSection.prev());
  }
}

/*
 *   If there's a next section, section to it
 * */
function goToNextSection() {
  if ($currentSection.next().length > 0) {
    goToSection($currentSection.next());
  }
}

/*
 *   Actual transition between sections
 * */
function goToSection($section) {
  //If the sections are not changing and there's such a section
  if (!isAnimating && $section.length) {
    //setting animating flag to true
    isAnimating = true;

    //Sliding to current section
    TweenLite.set($currentSection, {
      autoAlpha: 0,
      display: 'none'
    });

    $currentSection = $section;
    $background.classList = "";

    TweenLite.set($currentSection, {
      display: 'block'
    });
    TweenLite.set($background, {
      className: 'bg-' + ($sections.index($currentSection) + 1)
    });
    //console.log($sections.index($currentSection) + 1);
    TweenLite.fromTo($background, 0.6, {
      scale: 0.9,
      autoAlpha: 0
    }, {
      scale: 1,
      autoAlpha: 1,
      ease: Power1.easeOut,
      onComplete: onSectionChangeEnd,
      onCompleteScope: this
    });
    TweenLite.fromTo($currentSection, 0.6, {
      autoAlpha: 0
    }, {
      autoAlpha: 1,
      ease: Power1.easeOut,
    });
    

    //Animating menu items
    TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter(".active"), 0.5, {
      className: "-=active"
    });

    TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter("[href=#" + $currentSection.attr("id") + "]"), 0.5, {
      className: "+=active"
    });

  }
}

/*
 *   Once the sliding is finished, we need to restore "isAnimating" flag.
 *   You can also do other things in this function, such as changing page title
 * */
function onSectionChangeEnd() {
  isAnimating = false;
}

/*
 *   When user resize it's browser we need to know the new height, so we can properly align the current section
 * */
function onResize(event) {

  //This will give us the new height of the window
  var newPageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

  /*
   *   If the new height is different from the old height ( the browser is resized vertically ), the sections are resized
   * */
  if (pageHeight !== newPageHeight) {
    pageHeight = newPageHeight;

    //This can be done via CSS only, but fails into some old browsers, so I prefer to set height via JS
    TweenLite.set([$sectionsContainer, $sections], {
      height: pageHeight + "px"
    });

    //The current section should be always on the top
    TweenLite.set($sectionsContainer, {
      scrollTo: {
        y: pageHeight * $currentSection.index()
      }
    });
  }

}
```

```css
body,
div,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
  background-color: #000;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.sections-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

.section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#section-1 {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.section .centered h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.section .centered p {
  text-align: center;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.bg-1 {
  background-color: #5A4748;
}

.bg-2 {
  background-color: #45959b;
}

.bg-3 {
  background-color: #778899;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>


<div id="background"></div>
<div class="sections-container">

  <div class="section" id="section-1">
    <div class="centered">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="section" id="section-2">
    <div class="centered">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="section" id="section-3">
    <div class="centered">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that is what i want it to do the only problem now is when you scroll back up it goes to a zero spot and colors no longer show

Comment: thanks so much I didnt think of moving the bg container